# Java Strings storing byte arrays

Tags: java, string, arrays

I want to store a byte array wrapped in a String object.  Here's the scenario

1. The user enters a password.
2. The bytes of that password are obtained using the getBytes() String method.
3. They bytes are encrypted using java's crypo package.
4. Those bytes are then converted into a String using the constructor new String(bytes[])
5. That String is stored, or otherwise passed around (NOT changed)
6. The bytes of that String are obtained and they are different then the encoded bytes.

Here's a snippet of code that describes what I'm talking about.

```
String s = "test123";
byte[] a = s.getBytes();
byte[] b = env.encrypt(a);
String t = new String(b);
byte[] c = t.getBytes();
byte[] d = env.decrypt(c);
```

Where env.encrypt() and env.decrypt() do the encryption and decryption.  The problem I'm having is that the b array is of length 8 and the c array is of length 16.  I would think that they would be equal.  What's going on here?  I tried to modify the code as below

```
String s = "test123";
Charset charset = Charset.getDefaultCharset();
byte[] a = s.getBytes(charset);
byte[] b = env.encrypt(a);
String t = new String(b, charset);
byte[] c = t.getBytes(charset);
byte[] d = env.decrypt(c);
```

but that didn't help.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is `env` in your code examples?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's not a good idea to store binary data in a String object. You'd be better off using something like Base64 encoding, which is intended to make binary data into a printable string, and is completely reversible.

In fact, I just found a public domain base64 encoder for Java: http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/

Comment: +1 take the password, encrypt it, convert to base64 string (suggest using Apache Commons Codec for the last bit).

Comment: It's also not a good idea to store secrets in String objects (the password input or the decrypted output) unless you have absolutely no choice.  This is because there's no way to clear a String - once it's in memory, a String doesn't get overwritten until the memory is garbage collected AND the memory allocator decides to reallocate that section of memory.

Comment: Care to explain why it's a bad idea to store binary data in a string obj? I'm not saying I disagree, but it's usually a good idea to substantiate your claims.

Comment: The API documentation for the String class itself says "The String class represents character strings." Further down, it also says "A String represents a string in the UTF-16 format...". Basically, it is a smart object for storing character data, where you want a dumb object for storing binary data.

Answer (score 11):

Several people have pointed out that this is not a proper use of the `String(byte[])` constructor.  It is important to remember that in Java a `String` is made up of characters, which happen to be 16 bits, and not 8 bits, as a byte is.  You are also forgetting about character encoding.  Remember, a character is often not a byte.

Let's break it down bit by bit:

```
String s = "test123";
byte[] a = s.getBytes();
```

At this point your byte array most likely contains 8 bytes if your system's default character encoding is `Windows-1252` or `iso-8859-1` or `UTF-8`.

```
byte[] b = env.encrypt(a);
```

Now `b` contains some seemingly random data depending on your encryption, and isn't even guaranteed to be a certain length.  Many encryption engines pad the input data so that the output matches a certain block size.

```
String t = new String(b);
```

This is taking your random bytes and asking Java to interpret them as character data.  These characters may appear as gibberish and some sequences of bits are not valid characters for every encoding.  Java dutifully does its best and creates a sequence of 16-bit chars.

```
byte[] c = t.getBytes();
```

This may or may not give you the same byte array as `b`, depending on the encoding.  You state in the problem description that you are seeing `c` as 16 bytes long; this is probably because the garbage in t doesn't convert well in the default character encoding.

```
byte[] d = env.decrypt(c);
```

This won't work because `c` is not the data you expect it to be but rather is corrupt.

Solutions:

1. Just store the byte array directly in the database or wherever.  However you are still forgetting about the character encoding problem, more on that in a sec.
2. Take the byte array data and encode it using Base64 or as hexadecimal digits and store that string:

   ```
   byte[] cypherBytes = env.encrypt(getBytes(plainText));
   StringBuffer cypherText = new StringBuffer(cypherBytes.length * 2);
   for (byte b : cypherBytes) {
     String hex = String.format("%02X", b); //$NON-NLS-1$
     cypherText.append(hex);
   }
   return cypherText.toString();
   ```

Character encoding:

A user's password may not be ASCII and thus your system is susceptible to problems because you don't specify the encoding.

Compare:

```
String s = "tést123";
byte[] a = s.getBytes();
byte[] b = env.encrypt(a);
```

with

```
String s = "tést123";
byte[] a = s.getBytes("UTF-8");
byte[] b = env.encrypt(a);
```

The byte array `a` won't have the same value with the `UTF-8` encoding as with the system default (unless your system default is `UTF-8`).  It doesn't matter what encoding you use as long as A) you're consistent and B) your encoding can represent all the allowable characters for your data.  You probably can't store Chinese text in the system default encoding.  If your application is ever deployed on more than one computer, and one of those has a different system-default encoding, passwords encrypted on one system will become gibberish on the other system.

Moral of the story:
Characters are not bytes and bytes are not characters.  You have to remember which you are dealing with and how to convert back and forth between them.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer.  I'm currently blocked by a third-party's poor choice of Types; I need to pass a String through their system which I will get back later in the same JVM, and I need to use bytes.  The encrypted size is very compact and I'm hoping to avoid Base64 encoding.  I wish there was a Charset which said "every-bit pattern is valid".

Comment: @CoryKendall You're mixing concepts. Lots of character encodings have "every bit pattern is valid". But in Java Strings there is only UTF-16.

Comment: Ahh I see, so wouldn't I be able to convert any bit-pattern to a ISO-8859-1 String and back into bytes without seeing changes?  Which would answer this question in a couple lines?

Comment: @CoryKendall The point is that there is no such thing as an ISO-8859-1 String in Java. You can have a byte array that contains such data, but not a char[] or String.

Answer (score 4):

In both cases, you are using the OS default non-Unicode charset (which depends on locale). If you're passing the string from one system to another, they may have different locales, and thus different default charsets. You need to use one *well-defined* charset to do what you're trying to do; e.g. ISO-8859-1.

Better yet, don't do the conversion, and pass the `byte[]` array directly.

Answer (score 3):

This is somewhat of an abuse of the String(byte[]) constructor and related methods.

This would work with certain encodings, and fail with others. Presumably your platform's default encoding is one of the ones where it fails.

You should use something like [Commons Code](http://commons.apache.org/codec/)c to convert these bytes to hex or base64.

Also why are you encrypting passwords instead of hashing them with salt anyway?

Answer (score 2):

Implement a StringWrapper class whose constructor takes a String arg and coverts it to a byte[]. Use "ISO-8859-1" encoding to ensure each char will be just 8 bits instead of 16. You can then obviously use encoding/decoding methods to manipulate those bytes.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't going to work properly.  Storing a byte as a string is only going to work right for the ascii set (and a few others).  If you NEED to store the encrypted result as a String, then what about converting the bytes to hex and then putting that in a String.  That would work.

I recommend you just keep the password as bytes.  There's no real reason to store it as a String (unless you want to see what peoples passwords are).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a definitive answer for you, but if I were working on this, I'd print out the string or byte at each step and compare them to see what's happening. Also, b holds a return value from env.encrypt, but c is a return value from .getBytes, so in a way you're comparing apples to oranges in that case.